# Giving objects the ability to recreate

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns

I'm putting together a game in Java. Basically, you need to avoid oncoming game objects. I want to recreate these objects once they have left the screen.

I'm trying to adhere to design patterns, I currently have a GameObject Factory that is responsible for creating the game worlds' objects. All of these objects are derived from an abstract GameObject. I was considering creating a Recreatable interface that exposed a recreate method, that recreate method then expects a GameObject Factory which in turn returns another random version of that game object.

Like this

```
public class Ghost extends GameObject implements Recreatable, Movable {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int dx;
    private int dy;

    public Ghost(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        dx = 3;
        dy = 5;
    }

    public void move() {
        // move logic ...
    }

    public GameObject recreate(GameObjectFactory gameObjectFactory) {
        return gameObjectFactory.getInstance("ghost");
    }
}
```

I could then just check if it's an instance of re-creatable and if so add that recreated object to my list of moving game objects instead of doing a switch case/if else block of all the possible game objects.

This is an example of how it would look with the recreate method

```
public class GameSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    private ArrayList<Movable> movables;
    private GameObjectFactory gameObjectFactory;

    public GameSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        gameObjectFactory = new GameObjectFactory(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            if (!myHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            ListIterator<Movable> movableListIterator = movables.listIterator();

            while (movableListIterator.hasNext()) {
                Movable movable = movableListIterator.next();

                movable.move(canvas);

                if (movable.hasPassedScreen()) {
                    if (movable instanceof Recreatable) {
                        Recreatable recreatable = (Recreatable) movable;
                        movableListIterator.set(recreatable.recreate(gameObjectFactory));
                    }
                }
            }
            myHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

The if/else would look more like this for the run method

```
        while (movableListIterator.hasNext()) {
        Movable movable = movableListIterator.next();

        movable.move(canvas);

        if (movable.hasPassedScreen()) {
            if (movable instanceof GhostObject) {
                movableListIterator.set(gameObjectFactory.getInstance("ghost"));
            } else if (movable instanceof WitchObject) {
                movableListIterator.set(gameObjectFactory.getInstance("witch"));
            } else if (movable instanceof VampireObject) {
                movableListIterator.set(gameObjectFactory.getInstance("vampire"));
            } else if (movable instanceof ZombieObject) {
                movableListIterator.set(gameObjectFactory.getInstance("zombie"));
            }
        }

    }
```

Is this a bad way of going about it?

Comment: The use case is not clear.  Show how this would be used, and contrast with what you think is the "other" way of doing things with a switch/case.

Comment: I've tried to update the question to reflect this

Comment: Why don’t you want to use the switch or if else?

Comment: Just if in the future I decided to add more enemy types, I also have the desire to add collectibles onto the screen and I would want them to be recreated at some point, I don't know if the first one is a more elegant approach or if the second one would be more advisable.

Comment: I was wondering why you couldn't just delegate the task of renewing the object to the game object factory?

Comment: So would you suggest I opt for the if//else? The creation of the object still happens through the use of the game object factory in the first method it just delegates the type of object that is passed to the object factory, e.g. the ghost class will tell the factory to produce a ghost object etc.

Comment: No. Behavior will still be the same, main difference would be that your game objects should have a method to return its name, and that's what the factory will use to call your getInstance method.